# Convert SVG include external CSS to image java

Tags: java, css, svg, jpeg, batik

I want to convert the SVG file into image. The problem is my SVG use the external CSS file and when I use [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html), it can not recognize the external CSS file, and it just shows the styles which are inline the SVG tags. Here is my sample code:

```
public static void svg2jpgBatik1() {
        JPEGTranscoder transcoder = new JPEGTranscoder();

        try {

            // Create a JPEG transcoder
            JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();
            // Set the transcoding hints.
            t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
                    0.8f);

            // Create the transcoder input.
            String svgURI = new File("D:\\SVG_PATH\\map.svg").toURL().toString();
            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

            // Create the transcoder output.
            OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\JPEG_PATH\\map.jpg");
            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);
            t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_ALTERNATE_STYLESHEET, "D:\\STYLESHEET_PATH\\style.css");
            t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.blue);

            // Save the image.
            t.transcode(input, output);

            // Flush and close the stream.
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

This line works :

```
t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.blue);
```

while this line doesn't work :

```
 t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_ALTERNATE_STYLESHEET, "D:\\STYLESHEET_PATH\\style.css");
```

into the SVG I've added this part :

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 
<defs>
    <link href="STYLESHEET_PATH\\style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>

  </defs>
```

Which applied the SVG when I open it in the browser but in batik it doesn't apply.

I also put the styles into the  tag in the SVG, but the result was the same.

The only style it could apply is the inline SVG style such as **fill="#FFFFFF"**:

```
<text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle"  x="624" xml:space="preserve" y="123.0" 
       fill="#FFFFFF"  >Sample Text</text>
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me to solve this problem or let me know any best alternatives for having styles for SVG from **External CSS** when I convert it to an image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for your hint. I've found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this line at the top of my SVG code :

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css" ?>
```

instead of this part after the SVG tag:

```
<defs>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>

  </defs>
```

and now it makes the image with styles from the external CSS file.

So the SVG file would be :

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css" ?>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
```